# Concurrent Matrix multiplication. Adapter pattern usage

Tags: java, design-patterns, concurrency, io

The simple structure of my problem:
1. Two files matrix1.csv and matrix2.csv
2. Class "MatrixReader" that read from files ( provide method read as collection or as Array ; validate and etc )
3. Validation class - ( provide methods:  if matrices could be multiplied ( rule NxM to MxK ) ; if matrices contain bad characters and etc )
4. Class "MatrixMultiplication" that multiplied matrices extends thread provides methods: ( multiplication in multithread; multiplication in single thread; validation that multithread calc equal single thread calc )

My questions are:
  1. Do I correctly understand that "MatrixReader" should implement Adopter pattern? if no what patterns should I use in my use case?
  2.The second question is the validation of multiplication ( single thread - multithread ) should be in "MatrixMultiplication" class or there are better options? Many thx in advance!

Comment: The adapter pattern mainly used if you have an existing class with an interface and you want to use it with another class that expects a different one without modifiying its source. Since you are designing your structure right now (as I understand) I see no need for using this pattern. As I understand `MatrixMultiplication` will use `MatrixReader` (which has the `Validation` as dependency) to read the files, then on the returned value it performs the multiplication: the interface of the reader is used by `MatrixMultiplication`. If the interface doesnt match and cannot be modified, use adapter.

Answer (score 1):

The MatrixReader must read from two file formats? Then you might consider using a Strategy. If the reading&validation processes have a similar structure, you might use Template Method. I can't see a need for Adapter in what you write. More importantly, design patterns are all about **intent**, it may be useful to use them where their flexibility is required, but oftentimes the code is simpler without them.